# Server timezone changed to PHT but logs still written in MST?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, timezone, date

A couple of days ago, I updated the timezone on an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server using `$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`.

Today I noticed while tailing the mail log, that the times were still 15 hours behind. I immediately checked the server `date` but it's set to PHT as expected.

The following shows the last line of the terminated, tailed log (written just seconds earlier), followed by the `data` command.

```
Sep 20 01:24:07 s2 postfix/smtpd[13740]: disconnect from mail1282.news.laredoute.co.uk[208.85.54.19]
^C
root@s2:~# date
Fri Sep 20 16:24:12 PHT 2013
```

I've tried reloading Postfix, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changing the system time zone, you need to restart the system logger (or any other service that uses the timezone).

Answer (score 2):

If Postfix is chrooted, you may need to copy `/etc/localtime` to your chroot/etc dir i.e: `/var/spool/postfix/etc/localtime` for Postfix to see it.

Make sure `/etc/localtime` is not a symlink, if it is, then you will need to copy the actual timezone file from `/usr/share/zoneinfo/country/city`

Comment: After backing up `/var/spool/postfix/etc/localtime`, I over-wrote it with the copy form `/etc/localtime` and restarted Postfix. It still hasn't picked up the changes, although I do note that the old localtime file that I backed up does have references to MST in it.